# Sorting from file Android

Tags: android, sorting

I want to get text from file, and show it on TextView sorted.

I have class called RankActivity where I with zapisi() method writing one string and one integer called poenibrojanje to the file called 3.txt.

```
public void zapisi() {
    // WRITING
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String a = txtIme.getText().toString();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("3.txt", MODE_APPEND);

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        osw.write("Ime: " + a + "  Poeni: " + a1.poenibrojanje + eol);

        // Log.d("Writing", "This is writing log: " + a +
        // +a1.poenibrojanje);

        // osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also I have class where I read stuff from file, and show it in TextView. That class is called RankPrikazActivity and here is full code.

package com.test.brzoracunanje;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RankPrikazActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView tvRank, tvRankPrikaz;
Button btnPovratak;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rankprikaz);

    tvRank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRank);
    tvRankPrikaz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRankPrikaz);
    btnPovratak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPovratak);
    btnPovratak.setOnClickListener(this);
    citaj();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PocetnaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}

public void citaj() {
    // READING
    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("3.txt")));
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line + eol);
        }
        //Log.d("Reading log", "This is reading log:" + buffer);
        //System.out.println(buffer);
        tvRankPrikaz.setText(buffer.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

With method called citaj() method under this class, I read it from file and show it in TextView with this line:

```
   tvRankPrikaz.setText(buffer.toString());
```

Now I want to show it on this text box sorted by integer poenibrojanje from RankActivity class.

How to do it?

Comment: It's good practice to do your naming (classes,fields,methods etc) based on English words.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now why I should do English naming. Is there anyway to sort by poenibrojanje integer from RankActivity class, where I also write it to file and read it and  show it sorted with RankPrikazActiviy class.

Comment: Could show data representation in the file?

Comment: I  sent you pm on Twitter. Repesentaion data looks like this: Nikola 20 Nikola is String called "a", and 20 is intger called poenibrojanje.

Comment: While you are reading the file try to split the string you are fetching from the file in two (or more strings) where each will be the name and the other will be the numerical values. Add them in separate Lists. Put them in Map<Integer (or Double), String>. Sort the List with numerical data. Then just readd to the Map each value from the sorted one to the mapped value. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public void citaj() {
    // READING
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("3.txt")));
        String line;
        TreeMap<Integer,String> sorted_map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>(new Comparator(){
          public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
            Integer i1 = (Integer)o1;
            Integer i2 = (Integer)o2;
            return -(i1.compareTo(i2));
          }
          public boolean equals(Object o1){
            return this == o1;
          }
        });
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
          Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
          Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher(line);
          makeMatch.find();
          Integer inputInt = Integer.valueOf(makeMatch.group());
          sorted_map.put(inputInt, line);
        }
        //Log.d("Reading log", "This is reading log:" + buffer);
        //System.out.println(buffer);
        String toOutput = "";
        for(Integer i: sorted_map.keySet()){
          toOutput += sorted_map.get(i) + "\n";
        }
        tvRankPrikaz.setText(toOutput);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is how rank looks unsoretd: http://www4.slikomat.com/11/1030/eua-unsort.jpg Here is how it looks by your code: http://www4.slikomat.com/11/1030/zi4-sorted.jpg It sorted it somehow but not in good order. I need it to sort by integer called poenibrojanje, at this picture it is "Poeni".

Comment: Second picture is with your code. I know where is problem. Listen, here I am putting reading result to String line, but in file 3.txt I have one string and one integer in line. So, It doesnt recognize that because it reads from file with String line.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your concern.

Comment: The method descendingKeySet() is undefined for the type TreeMap<Integer,String> thats error

Comment: Oh, you must be using java 1.5. I've updated my answer to address this.

Comment: Now I have this erros : Multiple markers at this line
 - Comparator cannot be resolved to a type
 - The constructor TreeMap<Integer,String>(new Comparator(){}) is 
  undefined

Comment: Make sure you import java.util.Comparator.

Comment: Now I have error on return this o1. Here it is that error     Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:RankPrikazActivity [line: 64] - 
  equals(Object)
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
  variable

Comment: Oh yea, sorry. that should be `==` not `=`. I fixed that.

Comment: I cant believe IT WORKS.:)))))))))) Thank you very much. God bless you. :) You are best helper on stackoverflow. :))

Answer (score 2):

Just put these lines to the reading part instead of your code:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    strings.add(line);
}
Collection.sort(strings);

String text = "";
for(String string : strings) {
    text += string + eol;
}
tvRankPrikaz.setText(text);
```

Comment: This is how rank looks unsoretd: www4.slikomat.com/11/1030/eua-unsort.jpg Here is how it looks by your code: www4.slikomat.com/11/1030/zi4-sorted.jpg It sorted it somehow but not in good order. I need it to sort by integer called poenibrojanje, at this picture it is "Poeni".

Comment: Do you want to sort it by the numbers or by the names?

Comment: I want to sort it by numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote you simple example of sorting by numbers.

All you have to do is to parse the integer from the string you fetch from file and put it as key for the map, and the string (link) for the value of that key...

This is example I just wrote. You need to adjust it by your needs.

```
 Map<Double, String> map = new HashMap<Double, String>();
        map.put(new Double(22.02), "TEST 1");
        map.put(new Double(12.3), "TEST 2");
        map.put(new Double(1.3), "Test 3");
        Set<Double> nums = map.keySet();
       Collection<String> strings = map.values();
        Object[] Arr  = nums.toArray();
        List list= Arrays.asList(Arr);
        Collections.sort(list);
        for(Object o: list)
            map.put((Double) o, map.get(o));


        for(Double d: map.keySet())
            Log.i("TEST", map.get(d));
```

Comment: Hvala, Nikola :) I will take look at this later, because I want to learn more about it, but now Kurtis Nusbaum code works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simples thing to do would be to use a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) instead. Then when you do the select query, you can just have the results sorted using the [ORDER BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) clause.